# How to create an HTML table from loading an excel (xls/xlsx) using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel

I am new to web development , I'm making a loading screen data from excel , I request your support for the following:

Within a modal jquery I have a button "Select File ..." which opens the file navigation for the user to select an .xls / .xlsx file when the user selects it makes reading and creates an HTML table with the same structure that you have read the excel ( tableizer style ) .

Is there a jQuery library that can help me with this? Do any other method known to paste data from Excel in html ? I am also using bootstrap .

I hope you can help me , thanks .

Comment: There are [libraries](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) for JavaScript that can deal with Excel documents, but if you can work with CSV files instead of XLS(X) files, your job will be much much easier.

Comment: You can't access the local file system directly from a webpage.

Comment: @TimWilliams sure you can access file loaded by manual selection or drag/drop. Can parse excel to html using library such as https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx without any server interaction

Comment: @charlietfl - I guess I'm getting old ;-)